# Third Party Cookies Setting in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11

How do you send cookies to third party using ColdFusion? I'm trying this way but it is not sending the cookies.

```
<cfcookie name="username" value="#getuser.uname#">
<cfcookie name="password" value="#getuser.password#">
<cfcookie name="login" value="true" domain="localhost" >
```

Comment: Please elaborate on `send cookies to third party`.

Comment: Are we talking about the `SameSite` problem?

Comment: @DanBracuk third party means 

setting cookies on cross domain 

i am accesing a coldfusion application on main site (third party site) via iframe and want to set and use the cookies of CF application opened in that iframe

using coldfusion 2018 10th updated latest server

Comment: @Miguel-F 

YES em using samesite attribute but not working

Comment: Check this post from Charlie on Adobe's blog [Addressing SameSite cookie issues, before Adobe offers an update that does](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2020/03/addressing-samesite-cookie-issues-adobe-offers-update/). It includes references that should help you.

Comment: Note that you should _never_ put a user's password into a cookie, especially not when it's clear text. Otherwise it can be easily stolen. You should use a session ID instead to identify a user's session and put the session related information into the SESSION scope or your database.